# oracle select query to fetch records of last 30 days without timestamp and no trunc should be used

Tags: oracle, timestamp

oracle select query to fetch records of last 30 days without timestamp and trunc function should not be used

```
select * from table where enterdate between today date and last 30 day before
```

I used `select sysdate,(sysdate-30) from dual;`

But the time stamps is getting considered,but I want only date to be considered

And if I use `trunc((sysdate)-30)-6)` ,this trunc function was reducing the performace lot during execution for more records

hence index is used

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where enterdate between TRUNC(SYSDATE-30) and TRUNC(SYSDATE) ;
```

Any function call on a table column could cause impact(Unless a *function based index* is over it), but ***not*** on Values. Now, when we do `TRUNC(sysdate)` , this happens only once and involves very negligible cost , since it doesnt work on a Column.

`TRUNC(SYSDATE)` would nullify the *TIME* Element in current time will `'00:00:00'` . So the `BETWEEN` operation is perfect! and your INDEX's range scan would be happening

Comment: Now the index is used for this Query.